# What happens if I clear data in my settings

Tags: android-device-manager

I would like to figure out what to clear data on and what not to clear data on because I dont want to lose anything important

Comment: Data of an app is data related to that application that is stored due its probable requirement in the future, unlike cache, that is only required for a short period of time and gets obsolete very quickly. For example, a game's data includes saved games, game settings, log in cookies etc.

Answer (score 0):

just like phones when you factory reset it, it will go into its original state